# Out of memory in io_realm_internal_

Tags: android, realm

Hi i know i have posted the same question before, but can't seem to find the correct approach.
This is my class that is called by a Service if there is any changes in the contacts. A point to note is that the service keeps on calling continuously and maybe causing the memory leak, don't know for sure.

Here's the code for Service Class:

```
public class ContactsSyncService extends Service {


public static  int count =0;
int k = 0;

public static boolean contactUpdated = false;
ContentObserver mObserver;
public  Context contextService = ContactsSyncService.this;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;


}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            k++;


            if (!contactUpdated)
            {
                contactUpdated = true;
                Logger.debug("Contact Update to start -->");
                FetchLocalContacts.refreshingContactsDB();
            }
        }
    };
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, true, mObserver);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mObserver);
}
```

}

Here's my Class that causes the memory leak:

```
 public static void parseContactstoContactsDB()
{

    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Realm realmFetchFirstTime = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance());

            ContentResolver cr = ApplicationController.getInstance()
                    .getContentResolver();


            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,null,null, null);

            String duplicateName = "";
            String duplicatePhone = "";

            if( phones.getCount() >0)
            {

                final int nameIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                final int numberIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                while (phones.moveToNext())
                {

                    String name = phones.getString(nameIndex);
                    String phoneNo = phones.getString(numberIndex);



                    if(phoneNo!=null&&!phoneNo.isEmpty())
                    {

                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(" ", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("(", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(")", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("-", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u00a0", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u202c", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u2011", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u202a", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("*", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("#", "");

                        if (phoneNo.length() >= 5)
                        {

                            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicateName)&&phoneNo.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicatePhone))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            duplicateName = name;
                            duplicatePhone = phoneNo;

                            String formattedPhoneNumber;
                            formattedPhoneNumber = parseNumber(phoneNo);

                            realmFetchFirstTime.beginTransaction();
                            R_LocalContactDB rContacts = realmFetchFirstTime.createObject(R_LocalContactDB.class);
                            rContacts.setName(name);
                            rContacts.setPhone(formattedPhoneNumber);
                            realmFetchFirstTime.commitTransaction();


                            Logger.debug("Formatted Contacts -->  Name: "
                                    + name
                                    + " --  Phone No: "
                                    + formattedPhoneNumber);
                        }

                    }

                }
                phones.close();

            }

            realmFetchFirstTime.close();
           // getNumbersFromDBAndUpdate();
        }
    });
    background.start();

}



public static void getNumbersFromDBAndUpdate()
{

    Realm realmServer = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance());
    RealmResults<R_LocalContactDB> query = realmServer.where(R_LocalContactDB.class).findAll();
    Logger.debug("Contact Update updating to server -->");

    for (int i = 0; i < query.size(); i++)
    {
        phoneNumberJsonArray.put(query.get(i).getPhone());
    }

    try
    {
        uploadContactJsonBody.put("phone_numbers", phoneNumberJsonArray);

        Logger.debug("LocalContacts RequestJson ---> "
                + uploadContactJsonBody.toString());
        AppPreferenceManager.getInstance().setContactPref(1);

        UploadLocalContactsToServerAsynTask test = new UploadLocalContactsToServerAsynTask(
                uploadContactJsonBody.toString(),
                new LocalContactsSyncCallBack()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void didFinishProfileSync(boolean bool,
                                                     String result) {


                        Logger.debug("Is ContactUpdated FetchContacts --> "
                                + bool);

                        setMatchedStatusToFalse();

                        AppPreferenceManager.getInstance().setContactUpdate(bool);
                        Intent roomIntent = new Intent();
                        roomIntent
                                .setAction("com.advisualinc.echo.fetch.local_contacts");
                        ApplicationController.getInstance().sendBroadcast(roomIntent);
                    }
                });

        test.execute();
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    realmServer.close();

}



public static void refreshingContactsDB()
{
    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            realmFresh = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance());

            createCountryDetailsArrayModel();
            R_LocalContactDB rCont;
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ApplicationController.getInstance()
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String simCountryISO = tm.getSimCountryIso();

            for (int i = 0; i < countryDetailsList.size(); i++)
            {
                if (simCountryISO.equalsIgnoreCase(countryDetailsList.get(i)
                        .getCode()))
                {

                    dialCodePrefix = countryDetailsList.get(i).getDial_code();

                }
            }


            AppPreferenceManager.getInstance().setContactUpdate(false);

            Logger.debug("Contact Update Refreshing Contact Started -->");


            ContentResolver cr = ApplicationController.getInstance()
                    .getContentResolver();

            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);

            String duplicateName = "";
            String duplicatePhone = "";

            if (phones.getCount() > 0)
            {

                final int nameIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                final int numberIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                while (phones.moveToNext())
                {
                    String name = phones.getString(nameIndex);
                    String phoneNo = phones.getString(numberIndex);

                    if (phoneNo != null && !phoneNo.isEmpty())
                    {

                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(" ", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("(", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(")", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("-", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u00a0", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u202c", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u2011", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u202a", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("*", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("#", "");

                        if (phoneNo.length() >= 5)
                        {
                            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicateName) && phoneNo.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicatePhone)) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            duplicateName = name;
                            duplicatePhone = phoneNo;

                            String formattedPhoneNumber;
                            formattedPhoneNumber = parseNumber(phoneNo);

                            R_LocalContactDB realmResults = realmFresh.where(R_LocalContactDB.class).equalTo("phone", formattedPhoneNumber).findFirst();

                            Logger.debug("Size: " + realmResults);
                            R_LocalContactDB rContacts = new R_LocalContactDB(null, null, false, 0);


                                if (realmResults == null)
                                {
                                    i++;
                                    realmFresh.beginTransaction();
                                    rCont = realmFresh.copyToRealm(rContacts);
                                    rCont.setName(name);
                                    rCont.setPhone(formattedPhoneNumber);
                                    rCont.setStatus(0);
                                    rCont.setMatchedWithRecent(true);
                                    //   Logger.debug("New Size: " + query.size());
                                    realmFresh.commitTransaction();
                                }

                               else if( realmResults.isValid())
                                {

                                   realmFresh.beginTransaction();
                                   if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(realmResults.getName()))
                                    {
                                        realmResults.setName(name);
                                    }

                                        realmResults.setMatchedWithRecent(true);

                                // Logger.debug("New Size Else Condition: " + query.size());
                                    realmFresh.commitTransaction();



                               }



                        }


                    }

                }
                ContactsSyncService.contactUpdated = false;



                realmFresh.close();

            }

            deleteExtraContacts();
            getNumbersFromDBAndUpdate();
        }
    });
    background.start();

}



private static void deleteExtraContacts()
{



            Realm realmDelete = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance());
            RealmResults<R_LocalContactDB> query = realmDelete.where(R_LocalContactDB.class).equalTo("matchedWithRecent", false).findAll();
            realmDelete.beginTransaction();

            for (int i = 0; i < query.size(); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    query.remove(i);

                }
                catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                {
                    Logger.debug("Array Out of Bounds");
                }

            }
            realmDelete.commitTransaction();
            realmDelete.close();




}


private static void setMatchedStatusToFalse()
{


            Realm realmSetMatch = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance());
            realmSetMatch.beginTransaction();
            RealmResults<R_LocalContactDB> query = realmSetMatch.where(R_LocalContactDB.class).findAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < query.size(); i++)
            {

                R_LocalContactDB contactDb = query.get(i);
                contactDb.setMatchedWithRecent(false);



            }
            realmSetMatch.commitTransaction();
            realmSetMatch.close();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `realmFresh.close()` is guarded by `if (phones.getCount() > 0)` so if your `getCount() == 0` you will not close the Realm and leak memory. Have you tried moving the close() method outside the if-statement?

Comment: Yes, done that now a new error arises: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal State: Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?

Comment: at line:  if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(realmResults.getName()))

Comment: I have added isValid() for the condition but even then i keeps crashing

Comment: You will also get that message if you closed your Realm instance. Realm data is only available as long as the Realm is open. That also include RealmResults.

Comment: Can you please list out all the possible cases for out of memory problems?

Comment: 1) f you have Realms open on too many threads at the same time 2) If you  have a very big write transaction (MB of data). All other cases would cause you to run out of Java heap space first.